# return empty ajaxAsObservable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have this code

```
 allEditChanges
                    .debounce(250)
                    .distinctUntilChanged()
                    .flatMapLatest(function (text) {return  $.ajaxAsObservable({url:..., data:....} }).subscribe()
```

I need to make this conditionall so sometimes just omit the request.
I tried this way

```
 allEditChanges
 .debounce(250)
 .distinctUntilChanged(
 .flatMapLatest(function (text) {if(myFlag){
 return  $.ajaxAsObservable({url:..., data:....}))
}else{
return $.ajaxAsObservable({}); } }).subscribe()
```

but when `myFlag` is true , calls request to the current page.
Question how to omit the request ? How to not call any request on some condition

Comment: you can return `rxjs` `EMPTY` observable. `return EMPTY` or `return of()`

Comment: I think you are using rxjs4+ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/where.md)

```ts
allEditChanges
   .debounce(250)
   .distinctUntilChanged()
   .filter(() => !myFlag)
   .flatMapLatest(function (text) {return  $.ajaxAsObservable({url:..., data:....} })
   .subscribe()
```

Or return [Rx.Observable.empty()](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/empty.md)

```ts
allEditChanges
   .debounce(250)
   .distinctUntilChanged()
   .filter(() => !myFlag)
   .flatMapLatest(function (text) {
       if(myFlag){
         return Rx.Observable.empty();
       }
       return  $.ajaxAsObservable({url:..., data:....} })
   .subscribe()
```